# Internet Download Manager does not download PDF file on specific sites

Tags: firefox, pdf, download, download-manager

I am using [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) latest current version. It is working well. But on some sites it is not downloading PDF files.  Instead a box opens in Firefox like what to do with the file (save file or open with).

IDM does not take over that pdf download. If I set it PDF file to Preview in Firefox, in Firefox application settings, it is getting previewed in  Firefox but IDM does not take over it. If I set it to open with PDF extension of Foxit PDF viewer, it opens well. But problem remains that IDM does not take over it.

I have reinstalled Internet Download Manager as well. But no solution.

Can any one tell me the solution

Comment: Could it be that the link to the PDF is not pointing directly at the PDF file, but at a script providing the PDF, and that the IDM does not take over in this situation?

Comment: Exactly, you are right. But it was working in past. What should i do in this situation????

Comment: Install an older version of IDM to see if it works as expected.